# How to do the charset setting quickly in putty?

Tags: putty, performance

In my WinXP I write a bat file to start the putty  which is connected to my linux for development.

```
D:\PuTTY-v0.60\putty.exe username@192.168.190.34 -pw 123456
```

But  I have to set the charset to utf-8  manually everytime when I do the login.I think it's quite a waste of time.So how can I do the setting more quickly?Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`-load` option](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.7.3.1) to load a saved session:

```
putty -load "my session"
```

You can set up your session once, setting everything you need to set and then just start it using the above way.

Answer (score 3):

Open PuTTY without any arguments, change the charset settings, and save them into the "Default Session".